# How to echo an html with PHP and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to display a popup div on mysql row insert. Here is the what I trying to achieve.

I click on a button and it goes to the user.php page to perform some functionality. Now what I am stuck with is, I want to display a popup div if the row already exists and another div if the row does not exists and the insertion is successful (all this on the index.php page of course). Most of it I have implemented. The only part I am stuck with is with displaying these two popup divs on each of the functionalities.

I don't want an alert or anything, but the entire div. Please ignore any typo erros because the code with ajax call is working fine. I just need to get the divs displayed on the same page(index.php) on success and failure

I am aware that I should not be using mysql_* functions but right now I need to get this thing resolved first. Any suggestions would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
#overlay-back {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #1C1C1C;
    opacity    : .6;
    filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index    : 5;
    display    : none;
} 

#overlay_success, overlay_failure {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 10;
    display  : none;
} 
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.userlist').on('click', function () {
    $('#overlay_success, #overlay-back').fadeIn(100);
});
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $(function(){     
    $(".userlist").click(function(){
       var elementUser = $(this);

       var UserID = elementUser.attr("id");

       var info='UserID='+UserID;
       //alert(info);
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(){

        }
       });
     });
  });
});

   </script>


</head>

<body>

<div id="overlay-back"></div>
        <div align:center; style="position: relative; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; top: 50px;" id="overlay_success">
          <span>
          <h3 style="position: relative; align:center; color:white;"> Success!! </h3>
          </span>
    </div>

<div id="overlay-back"></div>
        <div align:center; style="position: relative; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; top: 50px;" id="overlay_failure">
          <span>
          <h3 style="position: relative; align:center; color:white;"> Failure. Already Exists!! </h3>
          </span>
    </div>

<a href="#" class="userlist">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**user.php**

```
if($_POST['UserID']){


$UserID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UserID']);

        $sql = "SELECT * from usera where uid = '$user_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            //display the div -> user already exists
        }else{
  //display the div (row inserted)
}
```

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 0):

Have UNIQUE IDs and do

```
$("#successdiv").hide(); 
$("#errordiv").hide();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "user.php",
    data: info,
  success: function(data){ 
    if (data.data=="error") { 
      $("#errordiv").show(); 
    }
    else {
      $("#successdiv").show(); 
    } 
 }
```

and on server

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
.
.
.
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { // or whatever the error is
    echo '{ "data":"error"}';
}
else { 
    echo '{ "data":"success"}';
}
```

Alternative is to return the message and just show it in a single div - perhaps change the class to Error if you want to change the colour or something

Comment: nope, it displays the same success div because it inserts the row everytime  I click on the button. Also, just incase, I am inserting the row from user.php

Comment: the only issue with the technique of yours I am facing is it always shows up the success div even if there is an error. I confirmed the ajax return data with an alert. and it return correct data, but the div that opens up is always that of  success. Am I missing somthng here?

Comment: Yes. If `data.error` is falsy then success is shown. console.log it and try turning it around - if (data.success) show success

Comment: ummm, I didnt get you

Comment: I put an alert(data) and it shows {"data":"success"} if the row is inserted and {"data":"error"} if it is not

Comment: nope, I dont, should I be using this for now? If yes, where?

Comment: returns an object Object data, I used it before echo-ing both error and success in user.php

Comment: perfect, that's what was missing "data.data". I have been stuck for hours trying to figure out this whole functionality altogether. I can't upvote your answer because I do not have 15 reputations yet. Thankyou so much :-).

Answer (score 0):

there is one way, your user.php is responsible to tell index.php if the operation is success, so simply do this:

```
//user.php    
  $user_id = isset($_POST['User_Id']) ? $_POST['User_Id'] : '';

  if($user_id){
     $UserID = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
     $sql = "SELECT * from usera where uid = '$user_id'";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
     //display the div -> user already exists
          echo 0;
     }else{
     //display the div (row inserted)
          echo 1;
     }
  }
```

and modify js code to show the right div:

```
<style>
    #overlay-back {
        position   : absolute;
        top        : 0;
        left       : 0;
        width      : 100%;
        height     : 100%;
        background : #1C1C1C;
        opacity    : .6;
        filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
        z-index    : 5;
        display    : none;
    }

    #overlay_success, overlay_failure {
        position : absolute;
        top      : 0;
        left     : 0;
        width    : 100%;
        height   : 100%;
        z-index  : 10;
        display  : none;
    }

    #overlay_failure, overlay_failure {
        position : absolute;
        top      : 0;
        left     : 0;
        width    : 100%;
        height   : 100%;
        z-index  : 10;
        display  : none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.userlist').on('click', function () {
            var elementUser = $(this);

            var UserID = elementUser.attr("id");
            //alert(info);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "user.php",
                data: {
                    User_Id:UserID
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == 0){
                        $('#overlay_failure, #overlay-back').fadeIn(100);
                    }
                    if(data == 1){
                        $('#overlay_success, #overlay-back').fadeIn(100);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

usually the ajax api returns json data, so this is not so regular.

I think you should pay attention to these codes:

```
 //index.php
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "user.php",
                    data: {
                        User_Id:UserID
                    },
```

and

```
//user.php
$user_id = isset($_POST['User_Id']) ? $_POST['User_Id'] : '';
```

and

```
//index.php
 success: function(data){
                        if(data == 0){
                            $('#overlay_failure, #overlay-back').fadeIn(100);
                        }
                        if(data == 1){
                            $('#overlay_success, #overlay-back').fadeIn(100);
                        }
                    }
```

It works on my computer except for the mysql part:
[image]

here you go....

```
<!-- link jQuery  -->
<html>
<head>

    <style>
        #overlay-back {
            position   : absolute;
            top        : 0;
            left       : 0;
            width      : 100%;
            height     : 100%;
            background : #1C1C1C;
            opacity    : .6;
            filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
            z-index    : 5;
            display    : none;
        }

        #overlay_success, overlay_failure {
            position : absolute;
            top      : 0;
            left     : 0;
            width    : 100%;
            height   : 100%;
            z-index  : 10;
            display  : none;
        }

        #overlay_failure, overlay_failure {
            position : absolute;
            top      : 0;
            left     : 0;
            width    : 100%;
            height   : 100%;
            z-index  : 10;
            display  : none;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.userlist').on('click', function () {
                var elementUser = $(this);

                var UserID = elementUser.attr("id");
                UserID = 'fdsa';
                //alert(info);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "user.php",
                    data: {
                        User_Id:UserID
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        if(data == 0){
                            $('#overlay_failure, #overlay-back').fadeIn(100);
                        }
                        if(data == 1){
                            $('#overlay_success, #overlay-back').fadeIn(100);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>



</head>

<body>

<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div align:center; style="position: relative; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; top: 50px;" id="overlay_success">
          <span>
          <h3 style="position: relative; align:center; color:white;"> Success!! </h3>
          </span>
</div>

<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div align:center; style="position: relative; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; top: 50px;" id="overlay_failure">
          <span>
          <h3 style="position: relative; align:center; color:white;"> Failure. Already Exists!! </h3>
          </span>
</div>

<a class="userlist">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You likely want to hide a previously show error when the user clicks

Comment: my ajax call is returning 0 and 1 properly, but the divs do not display

Comment: moreover, now it is not inserting the row at all

Comment: my index.php code does not include two of your displaying tags..... you should add them

Answer (score -1):

php code :

```
if($_POST['UserID']){


 $UserID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UserID']);

    $sql = "SELECT * from usera where uid = '$user_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
      echo mysql_num_rows($result);
    }else{
      echo mysql_num_rows($result);
  //display the div (row inserted)
}
```

script :

```
 $(function(){     
$(".userlist").click(function(){
   var elementUser = $(this);

   var UserID = elementUser.attr("id");

   var info='UserID='+UserID;
   //alert(info);
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "user.php",
    data: info,
    success: function(response){
       if(response > 0){
        $("#overlay_failure").css("display","block");
        }else{
          $("#overlay_success").css("display","block");
        }

    }
   });
 });
});
});
```

Comment: You need some syntax checking. You are lacking a bracket and this `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
      echo mysql_num_rows($result);
    }else{
      echo mysql_num_rows($result);` is the same as `echo mysql_num_rows($result);` - You also might want to hide a previously shown error div